# Why wont Tkinter label update?

Tags: python, tkinter

The label wont update and say something when I press the 'Generate Password' button.

I tried to make a variable which, depending on it's value, the password strength label would say the strength of the password. But for some reason the label isn't updating at all and is staying blank.

To fix this I tried multiple things, like putting the part where I set the label's text into the function, and even moving parts of the code around, but to no avail. I have no clue what to do at this point.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
import random

# window
root = ttk.Window(themename='darkly')
root.title("PyPass")

width = 350
height = 210

screenWidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screenHeight = root.winfo_screenheight()

x = (screenWidth/2) - (width/2)
y = (screenHeight/2) - (height/2)

root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, x, y))


# tabs
tabs = ttk.Notebook(bootstyle="dark")

mainTab = Frame(tabs)
settingsTab = Frame(tabs)

tabs.add(mainTab, text="Main")
tabs.add(settingsTab, text="Settings")
tabs.pack()

# labelframes
lengthLabel = ttk.LabelFrame(settingsTab, text="Password Length", padding=5)
lengthLabel.pack()

characterTypeLabel = ttk.LabelFrame(settingsTab, text="Character Types", padding=5)
characterTypeLabel.pack()

generateLabel = ttk.LabelFrame(mainTab, text="Generation", padding=5)
generateLabel.pack()

# textbox
lengthEntry = ttk.Entry(lengthLabel, bootstyle="secondary")
lengthEntry.grid(row=0, column=0)

# checkboxes
uppercaseVar = IntVar()
uppercaseCheckbox = ttk.Checkbutton(characterTypeLabel, text="Uppercase", bootstyle="success-checkbutton", variable=uppercaseVar)
uppercaseCheckbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)

lowercaseVar = IntVar()
lowercaseCheckbox = ttk.Checkbutton(characterTypeLabel, text="Lowercase", bootstyle="success-checkbutton", variable=lowercaseVar)
lowercaseCheckbox.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)

numbersVar = IntVar()
numbersCheckbox = ttk.Checkbutton(characterTypeLabel, text="Numbers", bootstyle="success-checkbutton", variable=numbersVar)
numbersCheckbox.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)

specialCharVar = IntVar()
specialCharCheckbox = ttk.Checkbutton(characterTypeLabel, text="Special Characters", bootstyle="success-checkbutton", variable=specialCharVar)
specialCharCheckbox.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)

passwordStrength = 0

# generate password function
def generatePassword():
    uppercase = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    lowercase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    numbers = "1234567890"
    specialChar = "!@#$%^&*()_+=-"
    password = ""
    length = int(lengthEntry.get())
    global passwordStrength

    if uppercaseVar.get() == 1:
        password += uppercase
        passwordStrength += 1
    
    if lowercaseVar.get() == 1:
        password += lowercase
        passwordStrength += 1
    
    if numbersVar.get() == 1:
        password += numbers
        passwordStrength += 1
    
    if specialCharVar.get() == 1:
        password += specialChar
        passwordStrength += 1
    
    password = "".join(random.sample(password, length))
    passwordText.delete("1.0", END)
    passwordText.insert(END, password)

# generate password button
generateButton = ttk.Button(generateLabel, text="Generate Password", bootstyle="success", command=generatePassword)
generateButton.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=5)

# textbox to view generated password
passwordText = ttk.Text(generateLabel, height=1, width=20)
passwordText.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=5)

strengthText = tk.StringVar()

if passwordStrength <= 0:
    strengthText.set("")

if passwordStrength in range(1,2):
    strengthText.set("Weak Password")

if passwordStrength in range(3,4):
    strengthText.set("Fine Password")
    
if passwordStrength in range(5,6):
    strengthText.set("Good Password")
    
if passwordStrength in range(7,8):
    strengthText.set("Strong Password")

# password strength label
strengthLabel = ttk.Label(generateLabel, textvariable=strengthText)
strengthLabel.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)

# mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of reasons.

1. the logic that checks the password strength is in the global scope and isn't checked when you press the button, you need to include it inside of the function scope.
2. your range functions are only a single digit so you are skipping all of the numbers in between.  The range function does not include the stop value so you need to increase it by 1 for each call.

For example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
import random

# window
root = ttk.Window(themename='darkly')
root.title("PyPass")

width = 350
height = 210

screenWidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screenHeight = root.winfo_screenheight()

x = (screenWidth/2) - (width/2)
y = (screenHeight/2) - (height/2)

root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, x, y))


# tabs
tabs = ttk.Notebook(bootstyle="dark")

mainTab = Frame(tabs)
settingsTab = Frame(tabs)

tabs.add(mainTab, text="Main")
tabs.add(settingsTab, text="Settings")
tabs.pack()

# labelframes
lengthLabel = ttk.LabelFrame(settingsTab, text="Password Length", padding=5)
lengthLabel.pack()

characterTypeLabel = ttk.LabelFrame(settingsTab, text="Character Types", padding=5)
characterTypeLabel.pack()

generateLabel = ttk.LabelFrame(mainTab, text="Generation", padding=5)
generateLabel.pack()

# textbox
lengthEntry = ttk.Entry(lengthLabel, bootstyle="secondary")
lengthEntry.grid(row=0, column=0)

# checkboxes
uppercaseVar = IntVar()
uppercaseCheckbox = ttk.Checkbutton(characterTypeLabel, text="Uppercase", bootstyle="success-checkbutton", variable=uppercaseVar)
uppercaseCheckbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)

lowercaseVar = IntVar()
lowercaseCheckbox = ttk.Checkbutton(characterTypeLabel, text="Lowercase", bootstyle="success-checkbutton", variable=lowercaseVar)
lowercaseCheckbox.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)

numbersVar = IntVar()
numbersCheckbox = ttk.Checkbutton(characterTypeLabel, text="Numbers", bootstyle="success-checkbutton", variable=numbersVar)
numbersCheckbox.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)

specialCharVar = IntVar()
specialCharCheckbox = ttk.Checkbutton(characterTypeLabel, text="Special Characters", bootstyle="success-checkbutton", variable=specialCharVar)
specialCharCheckbox.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)

passwordStrength = 0

# generate password function
def generatePassword():
    uppercase = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    lowercase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    numbers = "1234567890"
    specialChar = "!@#$%^&*()_+=-"
    password = ""
    length = int(lengthEntry.get())
    global passwordStrength

    if uppercaseVar.get() == 1:
        password += uppercase
        passwordStrength += 1

    if lowercaseVar.get() == 1:
        password += lowercase
        passwordStrength += 1

    if numbersVar.get() == 1:
        password += numbers
        passwordStrength += 1

    if specialCharVar.get() == 1:
        password += specialChar
        passwordStrength += 1

    password = "".join(random.sample(password, length))
    passwordText.delete("1.0", END)
    passwordText.insert(END, password)

    if passwordStrength <= 0:
        strengthText.set("")
    if passwordStrength in range(1,3):
        strengthText.set("Weak Password")

    if passwordStrength in range(3,5):
        strengthText.set("Fine Password")

    if passwordStrength in range(5,7):
        strengthText.set("Good Password")

    if passwordStrength in range(7,9):
        strengthText.set("Strong Password")


# generate password button
generateButton = ttk.Button(generateLabel, text="Generate Password", bootstyle="success", command=generatePassword)
generateButton.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=5)

# textbox to view generated password
passwordText = ttk.Text(generateLabel, height=1, width=20)
passwordText.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=5)

strengthText = tk.StringVar()


# password strength label
strengthLabel = ttk.Label(generateLabel, textvariable=strengthText)
strengthLabel.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)

# mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

To demonstrate what I mean with the range function see below:

```
>>> list(range(3,4))
[3]
>>> list(range(6,7))
[6]
```

As you can see the value of the second argument is not included.

In your code you have:

```
if passwordStrength <= 0:
    strengthText.set("")

if passwordStrength in range(1,2):  # only checks 1
    strengthText.set("Weak Password")

if passwordStrength in range(3,4):   # only checks 3
    strengthText.set("Fine Password")
    
if passwordStrength in range(5,6):   # only checks 5
    strengthText.set("Good Password")
    
#if paswordStrength == 7:  <--- this line is roughly the same as the one below  
if passwordStrength in range(7,8):   # only checks 7  
    strengthText.set("Strong Password")
```

Of course none of that is relevant unless it is placed inside of the `generate_password` function scope, as I did in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Hold on, how come you use .set() to change the text? I think that it also affects it as a variable, however there is a much easier way of showing the strength of the text. Define the `PasswordStrength` label, but making its text an empty string. (like this)

```
strengthLabel = ttk.Label(generateLabel, textvariable="")
strengthLabel.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
```

Then you can use the `.config` method (this one is from tkinter) or `.configure` method (this one is from the super set of tkinter bootstrap - works with new widgets brought by tkinter bootstrap and I think it is better supported for bootstyle styling).

Then, with that, just change the text with any string you  want to set, no need of variable

```
if passwordStrength in range(1,2):
    strengthText.configure(text="Weak Password")
```

*Notice, I had deliberately set the parameter of `text`. It is like defining a widget parameters but only this time, I have to change them